# Rendering a single component presentation in DD4T

Tags: dd4t, componentpresentation

I have a page with several component presentations using the component template 'Promotion'. In my page view '_Page.cshtml' I wish to write out all component presentations using this template and for every second occurance write some HTML just after i've written the component presentation.

I would use the following code to write out all presentations of a certain template:

```
@Html.RenderComponentPresentationsByView("Promotion")
```

I figured I could replace this code with the following (where my **Model** = IPage):

```
@foreach (ComponentPresentation cp in Model.ComponentPresentations)
{
    if (cp.ComponentTemplate.Title == "Promotion")
    {                                   
        //Logic here to render my specific CP through HTML.RenderComponentPresentations() or something else?
    }
}
```

I need to replace my comment with code to achieve the same result as RenderComponentPresentationsByView but for a single component presentation.

any Ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved this by calling the method using RenderAction from my view:

```
Html.RenderAction("ComponentPresentationByObject", "MyComponent", cp);
```

Note: This was only possible once I'd added the following method to the abstract class DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.

```
public virtual ActionResult ComponentPresentationByObject(ComponentPresentation cp)
{
    try
    {
        return GetView(cp);
    }
    catch (ConfigurationException e)
    {
        return View("Configuration exception: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

I inherit the abstract class TridionControllerBase in a class local to my project, **MyComponent**.

Strangely enough it there is a commented method in the default DD4T implementation which would seem to (nearly) provide this. I initially tried uncommenting the provided DD4T method 'TridionControllerBase.ComponentPresentation(string componentPresentationId)' but this gave me two errors 
(1) You must use a unique name for the action result as overloading is not permitted on Controller classes. 
(2) An error stating that it could not implement an interface.

Therefore I made a unique method name then changed the parameter from IComponentPresentation to ComponentPresentation.

Answer (score 10):

Calling

```
Html.Partial("Promotion", cp);
```

from within your loop should do the job.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your answer was correct and did provide a solution. However, I ended up with: Html.RenderPartial("../ComponentTemplateViews/MyPromotion", cp);. Notice I've given the example here with a template name 'My Promotion', and that I had to hardcode removing of the spaces. You helped me realise that calling an ActionResult inside DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase was what I needed. This way I had access to GetView() and all my calls were then consistent. See my answer for the details. Thanks again